# Rendering my animation is black, but there is a light?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation

I'm normally a programmer in unity so i know very little about modeling and all that stuff so sorry if this is a stupid question :) What i'm trying to do is make a background video for the main menu.

When i'm in the normal 3d viewport with rendered materials turned on in the bottom and look through the camera everything is fine such as seen here.
[image]

However when i go to "Render Animation" in the render tab to make it into a video the view comes back as black even though there is a light as seen here.
[image]

Comment: Is your rendered video in the vse? your rendered animation and the vse aren't linked. It looks like your rendered animation is in blenders default tmp folder. Go to C:\tmp in your file explorer. You should see it as a string of pngs. Or if you really want to preivew it in blender click on Render, then hit Play Rendered Animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Never check the V.S.E. (the black screen you're seeing) for your rendered animation.**

To see the outputed footage go to your file explorer and type in C:\tmp at the top (if you are on Windows). There you should see a string of image files for your movie. You can change the output file format and where it outputs to *before* rendering it. To see the rendered animation from within Blender, hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>.

Comment: ahh i see now, whats the point of the "V.S.E" thing then? if its just black

Comment: The V.S.E. is for editing for editing videos and audio. if you notice when you go to the video editing screen, which where rendered your video, there is a "track" or timeline you can import audio, video, pictures, etc. V.S.E stands for Video Sequence Editor

Comment: *C:\tmp* is only the temp folder for Windows users.

Comment: @pycoder Yes, I noticed the OP was using windows 10, I don't know how to access the tmp file on a Linux or Apple OS.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have not imported the rendered video into the [VSE](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/sequencer/introduction.html). Look at where your temp folder is and see if the file(s) are all in there. Then import the video or image sequence into the VSE.

Temp folder:

[image]

Comment: Maybe you miss understood the question im not importing a rendered video I'm trying to render the animation in blender then save it as a video file, however as seen by my second picture the viewport from the camera is black despite there being light.

Comment: That's not "the viewport from the camera." That's the video sequence editor. If you hit render animation, then go to the VSE and add the images or the video that was rendered out (the video or image sequence will already be on your disk outside of blender).

Answer (score 0):

Check the "outlier" panel (top right by default) and make sure you didn't accidentally click on and thereby turn off (disable) object in render.